# Is there a way to listen to pans only with GoogleMaps API in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I've some code I need to execute when the user pans the map around in my app, both when the pan starts, is being dragged and ends. 
I already looked at `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE`  ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/events)), but the `REASON_GESTURE` is true not just for panning, but also for zooming and rotating, and I don't want to execute the code in those two cases.

Is there a way to further narrow down the reason to pan only? If not, do you know any workaround that could work to listen to pans only inside a map and have different codes for pan start, drag and end?

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
            if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
                //map is touched..do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can persist the `CameraPosition` on each trigger. Then use the comparison to decide whether to execute the code or not.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
            CameraPosition newPosition = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
            if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE
                    && oldPosition != null
                    && oldPosition.tilt == newPosition.tilt
                    && oldPosition.zoom == newPosition.zoom
                    && oldPosition.bearing == newPosition.bearing) {
                // map is panned..do something
            }
            oldPosition = newPosition;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the right way to go, but the new position must be fetched in a Runnable delayed by a few milliseconds, or the new position will be the exact same as the old one. Thank you very much!